# Why do I get "/bin/sh: Argument list too long" when passing quoted arguments?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, arguments, quoting

How long can be a command line that can be passed to `sh -c ''`? (in bash and in bourne shell)

The limit is much lower than that from the OS (in case of modern Linux).

For example:

```
$ /bin/true $(seq 1 100000)
$ /bin/sh -c "/bin/true $(seq 1 100000)"
bash: /bin/sh: Argument list too long
```

And how could I circumvent this problem?

**Update**

I want to note that `getconf` can't help here (because that is not a system limit):

```
$ seq 1 100000 | wc -c
588895
$ getconf ARG_MAX
2097152
```

**Update #2**

Now I've understood what is the point here. That is not a shell limit, that is a system limit but for the length of each argument, not for the entire arglist.

```
$ /bin/true $(seq 1 100000)
$ /bin/true "$(seq 1 100000)"
bash: /bin/true: Argument list too long
```

Thank you, CodeGnome, for the explanation.

Comment: Related: [Does "argument list too long"
 restriction apply to shell builtins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47443380/does-argument-list-too-long-restriction-apply-to-shell-builtins)

Comment: Also see [Argument list too long error for rm, cp, mv commands](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11289551/608639)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

#### TL;DR

A single argument must be shorter than MAX_ARG_STRLEN.

#### Analysis

According to [this link](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/argmax/):

> And as additional limit since 2.6.23, one argument must not be longer than MAX_ARG_STRLEN (131072). This might become relevant if you generate a long call like "sh -c 'generated with long arguments'".

This is exactly the "problem" identified by the OP. While the number of arguments allowed may be quite large (see `getconf ARG_MAX`), when you pass a quoted command to */bin/sh* the shell interprets the quoted command as a single string. In the OP's example, it is this single string that exceeds the MAX_ARG_STRLEN limit, not the length of the expanded argument list.

#### Implementation Specific

Argument limits are implementation specific. However, [this Linux Journal article](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6060) suggests several ways to work around them, including increasing system limits. This may not be directly applicable to the OP, but it nonetheless useful in the general case.

#### Do Something Else

The OP's issue isn't actually a real problem. The question is imposing an arbitrary constraint that doesn't solve a real-world problem.

You can work around this easily enough by using loops. For example, with Bash 4:

```
for i in {1..100000}; do /bin/sh -c "/bin/true $i"; done
```

works just fine. It will certainly be slow, since you're spawning a process on each pass through the loop, but it certainly gets around the command-line limit you're experiencing.

#### Describe Your Real Problem

If a loop doesn't resolve your issue, please update the question to describe the problem you're actually trying to solve using really long argument lists. Exploring arbitrary line-length limits is an academic exercise, and not on-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: That is not a system limit! that is shell limit!

Comment: I don't have `MAX_ARG_STRLEN ` on a system with `2.6.31`

Comment: @DennisWilliamson: I also (3.2.0-rc7-686-pae); but anyway, argument length is the point. The only question is how to find it.

Comment: @CodeGnome: There are systems without `MAX_ARG_STRLEN` (my and the system of Dennis). So we need to find another way to find this value.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson execve(2) says "On  kernel  2.6.23  and  later...the limit per string is 32 pages (the  kernel  constant  MAX_ARG_STRLEN), and the maximum number of strings is 0x7FFFFFFF." So it seems likely that your system does have it, but it's a kernel constant.

Comment: Ah, it's just not visible to `getconf` and it's not in `limits.h` (but it is in the `man` page). Thanks.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson Anytime. Just for the record, I also grepped the kernel headers and found that it's defined in `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.0.0-14/include/linux/binfmts.h` if one ever needs to redefine it.

Comment: Or if you don't have the source installed and you just need to look it up: `/usr/include/linux/binfmts.h`

Comment: @ToddA.Jacobs If you are correct, this would be another silly Linux deviation from the POSIX standard. POSIX only knows one limitation: The initial stack of a process must not exceed  `ARG_MAX`.

Answer (score 6):

I don't get that error message. My secret? Single quotes:

```
/bin/sh -c '/bin/true $(seq 1 100000)'
```

If I use double quotes, I get that error with every shell:

```
$ /bin/sh -c "/bin/true $(seq 1 100000)"
-bash: /bin/sh: Argument list too long
$ /bin/bash -c "/bin/true $(seq 1 100000)"
-bash: /bin/bash: Argument list too long
$ /bin/ksh -c "/bin/true $(seq 1 100000)"
-bash: /bin/ksh: Argument list too long
$ /bin/zsh -c "/bin/true $(seq 1 100000)"
-bash: /bin/zsh: Argument list too long
```

The argument list gets expanded in the current shell when double quotes are used as evidenced by the fact that Bash is the one issuing the error "-bash: ..." regardless of the shell being used to run the command. On my system `sh` is Dash, by the way.

This holds true even for other "host" shells:

```
$ dash
$ /bin/bash -c '/bin/true $(seq 1 100000)'
$ /bin/bash -c "/bin/true $(seq 1 100000)"
dash: /bin/bash: Argument list too long
```

Patient: Doctor, it hurts when I do this."
Doctor: Don't do that.

Comment: Dennis, single/double quotes is not a point. I used `$(seq 1 100000)` here only for demonstration purposes; it doesn't matter how you produce this long string; of course I need double quotes here because I need very long string. The main question is how long can be the argument of `sh -c ''`

Comment: @IgorChubin: The answer is that if it matters, you're doing it wrong. On my system, by the way, it's [131071](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11475732/26428).

Comment: @IgorChubin: See "Do Something Else" [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11475732/26428).

Comment: What a good idea :) but anyway, I suppose that CodeGnome have found the right answer. The real point is the length of an argument.

Comment: Just for completeness: `/bin/bash -c '/bin/true "$(seq 1 100000)"'` breaks too because of how the shell tokenizes strings. +1 for solving for Y in this X/Y problem, though--I think it's useful to have a published solution for related issues.

Answer (score 1):

Make a file with `#!/bin/sh` as the first line, then the put rest of your command on subsequent lines? :)

More seriously, you can also read commands from STDIN using the `-s` option, so you can generate your long command line and pipe it in to `/bin/sh -s`

Comment: You can do this even without `-s`; yes I know that; probably it is the best solution except situations when you need to use shell stdin for something else

Comment: I think CodeGnome has found the solution. See his answer.

Comment: Sort of - except that there's still a maximum command-line length, and the "for $(command that generates lots of args); do; done" structure is one command line which can go over that length.  Piping the commands in on STDIN (whether with `-s` or with `for arg in $(</dev/stdin)`) is really the only way to have actual unlimited "argument" support.

Answer (score 0):

on my os it's the max length obtained by dichotomy

```
/bin/sh -c "/bin/true $(perl -e 'print"a"x131061')"
```

so it gives 131071

but there is no reason to have a line as long ; if it's due to a large number of arguments, "$@" can be used instead; for example

```
/bin/sh -c 'command "$@"' -- arg1 arg2 .. argn
```