# /user/bin/awk: Argument list too long in awk

Tags: shell, awk, grep

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do I get “/bin/sh: Argument list too long” when passing quoted arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11475221/why-do-i-get-bin-sh-argument-list-too-long-when-passing-quoted-arguments)

I am using awk script inside a shell script and I am processing multiple files and for everytime I am getting the output from awk, processing it in shell and the feeding back the processd thing into awk script again.

But the problem here is, each time the data that is being processed is huge around 30000 lines which I am storing it in a single variable and I am passing into awk using the `-v` option.

So I am getting an error

> `/usr/bin/awk: Argument list too long`

Any remedy of how to solve this .. And am I clear with the question

Comment: Show some code, please. I'm assuming that "/usr/awk/bin" is a typo.

Comment: First hit when googling for argument list too long: http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6060

Comment: That's an odd path .. shouldn't it be `/usr/bin/awk`

Comment: The source of the error is that you are exceeding the command line buffer. See http://partmaps.org/era/unix/arg-max.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to pass too many arguments to `awk`. You shouldn't use `-v` to pass arbitrarily large amounts of data; feed it via a pipe to `awk`'s standard input instead.

(I can't show you example code without seeing a snippet of your code, since I don't fully understand how you're currently handling your data.)

Comment: Ya iI understood user point ...I have somehow resolved that error ...Now I am not passing any arguments to this but I am getting /usr/bin/ls Argument list too long... /usr/bin/expr ,, Argument list too long.. Any reason of why this error is because of ... As these statement's doesn't take arguments, then how come I am getign this error

Comment: @User: somehow, you are passing arguments to those commands. For example, how are you calling `ls`?

Comment: Were you forgetting to quote your variable? `awk -v var="$data" '...'`

Comment: No I havent .. My code is a loop it runs perfectly for the same ls comamnd without any error in the beginning and then it displays /ur/bin/ls error and then crashes .. I dun know the reason behind this