# bash: /usr/bin/bq: Argument list too long

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to load 7MB dump.sql file to bigquery using the following command:

while read -r q; 
   do
    bq query --destination_table '[project].[table]'                                       --allow_large_results "$q"
     done < <(grep '^INSERT' dump.sql);

But i get this error, " bash: /usr/bin/bq: Argument list too long "
what could be the solution for the same?
Kindly help .

Comment: Only 5 years late, but this might be helpful for others: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11475221/why-do-i-get-bin-sh-argument-list-too-long-when-passing-quoted-arguments