# Find and replace a huge list of strings in selected columns of a file

Tags: shell, csv, awk, sed, gsub

I have a large CSV file(~1GB) - data.csv
A variable with a huge list of Pipe separated strings.
`list="abc|def|ghi.........."`

**Objective** is to search **2nd and 3rd** columns of `data.csv` for each and every string listed in `list` variable and replace it with the string `unassigned`

Below is what i came up with,
`awk -v list="$list" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{gsub(list,"unassigned",$2)}{gsub(list,"unassigned",$3)}1' data.csv > data_new.csv`

It works fine as long as the list is small. Once the list variable crosses around 10k strings, it'll throw the error
`/usr/bin/awk: Argument list too long`

Is there any solution to handle this long list here? Totally new solution is also welcome. Thanks in advance.

*Note : Would prefer to avoid looping through list since it degrades the performance.*

Comment: I'm not seeing how that can work even if the list is only 2 values `list='foo,bar'` since the gsub will be looking for a regexp `foo,bar` instead of what I **think** you'd want which is `foo|bar`. [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output so we can help you.

Comment: Thanks for the update. there is a `tr "," "|"` which i missed here. Corrected the variable data.

Comment: is your line separated by `|` or `,` ?

Comment: data.csv is separated by `,` which is why i added `BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}` to define it as the seperator

Answer (score 1):

Do this instead if you're using bash:

```
awk '
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
NR==FNR { list=$0; next}
{ gsub(list,"unassigned",$2); gsub(list,"unassigned",$3) }
1' <<<"$list" data.csv > data_new.csv
```

See [Why do I get "/bin/sh: Argument list too long" when passing quoted arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11475221/1745001) and [Does "argument list too long" restriction apply to shell builtins?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47443380/1745001) for what's happening with your original code and how this solves the problem.

Comment: "list" is missing on the assignment.  Also `NR==1` perhaps better here...

Comment: Tried the snippet but no data comes out.

Comment: @karakfa thanks, corrected wrt `list`. wrt `NR==1` vs `NR==FNR` - I could go either way but at least NR==FNR lets you know the input is coming from the first input stream so I slightly prefer that.

Comment: @OptimusPrime try it now.

Comment: same result as before. data_new.csv is empty.

Comment: The "1" at the end should print the line out. but due to some strange reason its not printing anything out.

Comment: Assuming you'd have told us if there was any error message, the **only** way for that script to produce no output is if you don't provide it input. Add `{print FILENAME, $0}'` above the `NR==FNR` line to see what input it's getting. It is obviously untested though because you didn't provide anything for us to test against in your question.

Comment: There was no error, just nothing comes out. And i couldnt provide a test data set since i dont have the issue with small data set. Now when i added the print as suggested, data_new got filled with data.csv

Comment: Providing a small data set would let us test that the script does produce the expected output for that at least though. Don't you have the same problem you're having now (no output) with a small data set? You said data_new got filled with data.csv. You did NOT say that the first line of data.csv was the value of "$line" which is what would be expected. The implication is that either "$line" is empty or you aren't using exactly the script I posted to get it passed to the awk script or there's a bug in the awk script (untested since you didn't provide sample input) that isn't reading "$line"