# Using golang's os/exec, how can I copy stdout from one process to stdin of another?

Tags: go, io, stream

I want to emulate a bash pipe using go's [os/exec module](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/). Here's a dummy example in bash:

```
$ ls | wc 
      42      48     807
```

How can I emulate that in Go? Is there a way to do it with streams?

Comment: exact duplicate of [How to pipe several commands?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10781516/how-to-pipe-several-commands)

Answer (score 2):

[Via Brad Fitzpatrick, here's one way to do it](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/OHuyTpotrLw). You can reassign the `Stdin` property of the second command to the `stdout` writer from the first command.

```
    ls := exec.Command("ls")
    wc := exec.Command("wc")
    lsOut, _ := ls.StdoutPipe()
    ls.Start()
    wc.Stdin = lsOut

    o, _ := wc.Output()
    fmt.Println(string(o))
```