# Copying ssh public key to server

Tags: ssh, go

I'm trying to add a public key under my local $HOME/.ssh/ directory using Go.

I've been running multiple commands with this the same code without problem, but not for this particular one.

```
identity := fmt.Sprintf("cat %s/.ssh/%s.pub", fileUtil.FindUserHomeDir(), p.sshkey.name)
address := fmt.Sprintf("| ssh %s@%s 'cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys', p.projectname.name, p.host.name)

cmd := exec.Command(identity, address)

err := cmd.Run()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

Basically I'm trying to run:

```
cat /home/foo/.ssh/foobar.pub | ssh foo@bar.com 'cat >> ~/.shh/authorized_keys'"
```

Which works fine if I run it through the command line directly.

I want to run this program in different OS X machines, where some don't have ssh-copy-id installed. So, I'm not considering to use it.

But anyway, I'm open to other suggestions. Thank you in advance.

Comment: `exec.Command` isn't a shell, so there is no concept of `|`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10781516/how-to-pipe-several-commands-in-go

Comment: You can use exec.Command to execute shell though: `sh -c command`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to execute `/bin/sh -c "cat file"` to read a file in Go. Open the file normally, and give that to the ssh command

```
keyFile, err := os.Open(filename)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

cmd := exec.Command("ssh", "user@host", "cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys")
cmd.Stdin = keyFile

// run the command however you want
out, err := cmd.CombinedOutput()
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(string(out))
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

Comment: but when i want to copy-ssh-id, I didn't have the key installed in remote server. How to input my password? ```"ssh", "user@host"``` where to input the password?

Answer (score 1):

You could simply execute rsync or scp for this purpose.