# Using scanln while executing go binary with pipe

Tags: go, pipe

I have the following go code:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    if scanln_test() {
        fmt.Println("Success!")
    }
}

func scanln_test() bool {
    fmt.Print("Please type yes or no and then press enter [y/n]: ")

    var response string
    fmt.Scanln(&response)

    if response == "y" {
        return true
    } else if response == "n" {
        return false
    } else {
        return scanln_test()
    }
}
```

When execute the compiled binary via pipe, e.g.:

`$ echo "just-showing-how-pipe-affects-the-behavior" | ./scanln`

I get a infinite output of `fmt.Print` inside of `scanln_test` function. However when I don't execute it via pipe, everything works fine.

Is there a way to fix this?

UPD. fmt.Scanln returns "EOF" as an error when the binary executed with in pipe

UPD2. The example with echo above is just to make a point about the pipe, but I'm not looking to read the content of this echo in my go program. The real case looks like this: `wget -qO- http://example.com/get | sh -s "param"`. I have exec of go program inside of this downloaded shell script and I want my program to show dialogue to user with Y/N. I'm not sure whether it's possible at all, so for now I've decided to get rid of the pipe and run it separately like `wget -qO- http://example.com/get | sh && go-program "param"`.

Comment: Check your calls for errors.

Comment: fmt.Scanln returns EOF, is this the output of the command before pipe?

Comment: yes, it returns EOF because there's no more input. And you keep trying to read over and over even though there will never be any more input.

Comment: What would be the right way to read the input when the binary executed in pipe?

Comment: First call to `fmt.Scanln(&response)` reads "just-showing-how-pipe-affects-the-behavior", since it is not equal to neither "y" nor "n" it calls `scanln_test()` again in your else statement. But now Stdin is empty and closed so `fmt.Scanln(&response)` returns EOF error and response is null value string, so it didnt match again and calls `scanln_test()` again in else statement. And it loops forever in recursion. What did you expect? Does `$ echo "y" | ./scanln` runs as expected?

Comment: Whether it's from a pipe or not *makes no difference*. The right thing to do is check your errors and handle EOF by exiting or doing something else.

Comment: `$ echo "y" | ./scanln` runs well. Ok, now I understand that this caused by EOF in stdin, but what would be the right way to read user input when I use pipe to run?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`os.ModeCharDevice`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#FileMode):

```
stat, _ := os.Stdin.Stat()

if (stat.Mode() & os.ModeCharDevice) == 0 {
    // piped
    input, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(os.Stdin)
} else {
    // not piped, do whatever, like fmt.Scanln()
}
```

Comment: The condition always returns false, but anyway I tried to replace fmt.Scanln with `ioutil.ReadAll(os.Stdin)` and it returns `[119 104 97 116 101 118 101 114 10]` which is probably the same "EOF" returned by Scanln error

Comment: You must be doing something wrong. Save [this](https://play.golang.org/p/YvJwt6bw0N) file as `input.go` and try with `go run input.go` and `echo foo | go run input.go`. You'll see `not piped` and `piped` respectively.

Comment: I execute the compiled binary (Linux x64)

Comment: Doesn't matter, it works the same. See [here](http://dpaste.com/18QYWES.txt). Did you try the **exact** file I've linked? Also, what is your go version?

Comment: Sorry, I must have mixed up something. The condition works now. I tried to use `ioutil.ReadAll(os.Stdin)` as you suggested, but it just returns the content of what I have before the pipe. My golang version is 1.6

Answer (score 1):

So you need concurrent input from Stdin (pipe) and user Stdin (Keyboard):
 i think you answer is cat command see: [How can I pipe initial input into process which will then be interactive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843741/how-can-i-pipe-initial-input-into-process-which-will-then-be-interactive)
and: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)

see: [How to pipe several commands in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10781516/how-to-pipe-several-commands-in-go)
and [Go Inter-Process Communication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9366550/go-inter-process-communication)

there are 3 things to note:
first: it is good practice to check for all errors:
  in your case :

```
n, err := fmt.Scanln(&response)
```

second:
you are using recursive call (Tail Call) and it is not necessary here.
replace it with simple for loop and see:  [Tail Call Optimization in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12102675/tail-call-optimization-in-go)
3rd:
last but not least: in case of bad input your code loops for ever(consuming stack if compiler could not optimizes tail call)!
it is good to limit to 3.
example:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "strings"

type Input int

const (
    Timeout Input = iota
    Yes
    No
    Abort
    BadInput
)

func userInput(msg string) Input {
    var input string
    for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
        fmt.Println(msg)
        n, err := fmt.Scanln(&input)
        if n > 0 {
            switch strings.ToLower(input) {
            case "y":
                return Yes
            case "n":
                return No
            case "a":
                return Abort
            }
        }
        if err != nil {
            return BadInput // or panic(err)
        }
    }
    return Timeout
}
func main() {
    ans := userInput("Please type Yes,No or Abort and then press enter [y/n/a]: ")
    fmt.Println(ans)
    switch ans {
    case Yes:
        fmt.Println("Yes") // do some job
        //...
    }
}
```

Edit:
with this simple "y/n" you do not need to check is it pipe or not.
even simple std Read with one byte slice is good:

```
os.Stdin.Read(b1)
```

see my piping sample: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37334984/6169399

but in case your Stdin is pipe you may use:

```
bytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(os.Stdin)
```

to read all piped data all at once. but be careful to handle errors. 
you can check if stdin is associated with a terminal or a pipe then use appropriate code.
simple way to detect it is pipe or not :

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    info, err := os.Stdin.Stat()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("not a pipe")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("pipe name=", info.Name(), "pipe size=", info.Size())
    }
}
```

all in one sample code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

type Input int

const (
    Timeout Input = iota
    Yes
    No
    Abort
    BadInput
)

func userInput(msg string) Input {
    var input string
    for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
        fmt.Println(msg)
        n, err := fmt.Scanln(&input)
        if n > 0 {
            switch strings.ToLower(input) {
            case "y":
                return Yes
            case "n":
                return No
            case "a":
                return Abort
            }
        }
        if err != nil {
            return BadInput // or panic(err)
        }
    }
    return Timeout
}
func main() {
    info, err := os.Stdin.Stat()
    if err != nil {
        //fmt.Println("not a pipe")
        ans := userInput("Please type Yes,No or Abort and then press enter [y/n/a]: ")
        fmt.Println(ans)
        switch ans {
        case Yes:
            fmt.Println("Yes") // do some job
            //...
        }

    } else {
        fmt.Println("pipe name=", info.Name(), "pipe size=", info.Size())
        bytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(os.Stdin)
        fmt.Println(string(bytes), err) //do some jobe with bytes
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks! All 3 recommendations are useful, however, the original question remains unanswered – how to read user input when I use pipe to run the binary?

Comment: This was discussed here below http://stackoverflow.com/a/37539014/1826109. It helps to get the data I have before the pipe, which is not the case I'm looking for. My example `echo "just-showing-how-pipe-affects-the-behavior" | ./scanln` is just to make a point, but what I really have is something like that `wget -qO- http://example.com/get | sh -s "param"`. I have a binary exec inside of this shell script and I want it to show user dialogue with y/n