# Go - Pipe 3 or more commands with os.exec()?

Tags: go

How can I pipe 3+ commands together in Go (for example ls | grep | wc)? I've tried to modify this code that is for piping 2 commands, but can't figure out the correct way.,

```
package main

import (
    "os"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    c1 := exec.Command("ls")
    c2 := exec.Command("wc", "-l")
    c2.Stdin, _ = c1.StdoutPipe()
    c2.Stdout = os.Stdout
    _ = c2.Start()
    _ = c1.Run()
    _ = c2.Wait()
}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10953142/3761308

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pipe several commands in Go?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10781516/how-to-pipe-several-commands-in-go)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
package main

import (
    "os"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    c1 := exec.Command("ls")
    c2 := exec.Command("grep", "-i", "o")
    c3 := exec.Command("wc", "-l")
    c2.Stdin, _ = c1.StdoutPipe()
    c3.Stdin, _ = c2.StdoutPipe()
    c3.Stdout = os.Stdout
    _ = c3.Start()
    _ = c2.Start()
    _ = c1.Run()
    _ = c2.Wait()
    _ = c3.Wait()
}
```