# How do I add a tab delimiter in Golang exec.command

Tags: go, exec, cut, csv

I'm trying to execute the following command via Go:

**cut -f1 -d  $'\t' fileName | sort | uniq -d**

My code:

```
log.Printf("%s %s %s %s %s %s", "cut", "-f1", "-d ", "$'\\t'", fileName, " | sort | uniq -d")

r, e = exec.Command("cut", "-f1", "-d", "$'\\t'", sortedFile, " | sort | uniq -d").CombinedOutput()

log.Printf("o/p:%d", string(r))
```

This gives a bad delimiter error but the command printed runs on command line

Log snippet:

```
2020/09/17 13:27:13 cut -f1 -d  $'\t' /Users/samalhot/Documents/test_sorted.txt  | sort | uniq -d
2020/09/17 13:27:13 o/p:%!d(string=cut: bad delimiter
)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `$'\t'` ist shell syntax. In Go simply write `"\t"`. For pipes see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10781516/how-to-pipe-several-commands-in-go.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, that worked!

```
log.Printf("%s %s %s %s %s %s", "cut", "-f1", "-d ", "\t", sortedFile, " | sort | uniq -d")

r, e = exec.Command("cut", "-f1", "-d", "\t", sortedFile, " | sort | uniq -d").Output()

log.Printf("o/p:%d", string(r))
```