# Golang - how to spawn a process that takes a glob pattern as one of its command-line arguments?

Tags: go

From my bash shell, I am able to run this following command successfully - `scp <local-folder>/* <user>@<remote-host>:/var/tmp`.  All files in my `<local-folder>` are copied onto the remote location.

Now I am trying to run the above same command from my Go program, with `exec.Command()` but `scp` complains of "no such file / directory - `<local-folder>/*`' - the '*' is literally taken as a filename.  I want to replicate the same behaviour of `scp` I get when I run it from my Bash shell.  Here is the code snippet I am using:

```
    pushCmd := exec.Command("scp", "<local-folder>/*", "<user>@<remote-host>:/var/tmp")
    pushCmdOutput, err = pushCmd.CombinedOutput()
    fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, string(pushCmdOutput))
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `bash -c`, like here https://stackoverflow.com/a/30329351/965900 (it answers a problem with pipes, but just like the pipe, the glob pattern is a thing of the shell)

Comment: If you want `bash` to expand the `*`, then you need to execute `bash` (or simulate what it's doing yourself)

Comment: Aaargh!  Yes; that bash expands such glob patterns first, is something I missed.  Thanks @mkopriva and JimB

Comment: @SrivathsanM, just to complement the answers given, look at this complete example: https://go.dev/play/p/1cD9WamklgN.